# Can i return multiple tables in one Data Access Layer?

Tags: asp.net

I am currently learning n-tier architecture and trying to upgrade an old ASP.NET project.

In the project I had a Dataset in which multiple tables were being retrieved, the additional tables were thrown in to take advantage of caching and are not really used else where in the site other than for calculations for one of the main tables in the Dataset.

Moving towards an n-tier architecture I have an ObjectDataSource which points to a BLL, which then points to my DAL. The DAL Dataset still contains the 5 tables.

What I want to know is, should these extra tables be moved out and a separate DAL created for each?

If so, where should I pass the contents of the tables back into the BLL, via the ObjectDataSource's parameters or can I call the DALs from directly inside the BLL Select statement itself?

Comment: If you're passing `DataTable` objects around then your application is not correctly n-tier because the data persistence layer is not abstracting-away storage details from its consumers (e.g. if the storage schema changes, then all of the downstream consumers will need to be modified accordingly) - there is an exception to this if you're using `DataTable` objects to represent your entities as part of your design, but it's a bad code-smell and prevents the correct use of design-patterns when needed (because `DataTables` cannot contain logic, only data).

Comment: If you're using a DataTable at all, that's a code smell in my opinion. Get your objects into strongly typed models.

Comment: I understand that its code smell and that I should eventually turn my objects into strongly typed models. Assuming that they eventually will become strongly typed objects its the nature of calling them that I need help on, passed as parameters or called directly from the BLL?